# Training current location person flutter mobil app

Tags: flutter

I'm a new developer, my quation is can I track a current location of a person when the app is closed in the list of app open in background?

I'm a new developer, my quation is can I track a current location of a person when the app is closed in the list of app open in background? Thanks